# Frozen context menu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, bug-reporting

1-3 times per day I go to right-click an open program on my taskbar and [I get the standard context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl9BV.png) except nothing can be selected (can't click exit, and the menu continues to overshadow everything, have to log out to remove it) and eventually this freezes my whole system unless force an interrupt and logout to remove it. I assume it's the menu itself causing the rest of the OS to freeze as i am not experiencing any slowdowns before this event happens. Does anybody else get this?

Even if i manage to close the application i have right-clicked i have still a [permanent menu there which cant be exited..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb7YW.png), even if the menu was responsive (i've never had it become unfrozen) the 'quit' option is no longer there at this point..

This bug is not just for when I right-click Firefox it happens to other browsers too, browsers are the most common app i use so i don't know if it happens when right clicking other apps.

Comment: Sounds like a GNOME extension problem. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and temporarily disable ALL extensions, and see if the problem goes away. Edit your question to include the output of `ls -al .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Report back to @heynnema

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you're still having this problem, but I'm occasionally having frozen menus on Ubuntu 18.04. I don't know the cause, but I'm able to get rid of them by switching to a new workspace (CTRL-ALT-DOWN) - the menu is active for me on the second workspace.